# Escolhas do usuário em Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá. Estou a tentar criar um programa de interfaçe gráfica usando Tkinter(aprendi há pouco tempo) e queria que o usuário, ao escrever na caixa de entrada de texto e ao carregar no botão  ele imprimisse algo. Se escrever B maiúsculo imprime "a iniciar a bios" e se não escrever algo imprime "a iniciar o SO".
Código:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from Tkinter import *

#função de arranque da VM:
def arranque():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(950, 700)
    root.wm_iconbitmap('virtual-pc-1338544131.ico')
    root.title("Computador virtual PowerBIT v1.0")
    root.configure(background='black')
    machine = Label(root, text="Bem vindo à máquina virtual. Prima B para aceder ao BIOS ou ENTER para inciar o SO", fg="white", bg="black").grid(row=0)
    e1 = Entry(root, bg = "white", fg = "black" )
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    botao_de_arranque = Button(root, text="Iniciar", width=6).grid(row = 1, column = 1, ) 
    root.mainloop()
arranque()
```

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica, amigo. Usa [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *widget* [`Button`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) fornece um *callback* que permite fazer algo quando o usuário clicar no botão.

Veja um exemplo:

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():
    print "O usuario clicou no botao"

b = Button(text="Clique aqui", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

No código apresentado por você isso poderia ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from Tkinter import *

def btn_arranque(texto):
    # Fazer alguma coisa aqui ao clicar no botão
    if texto == 'B':
        # Fazer alguma coisa aqui caso o edit ter o texto 'B'
    else:
        # Fazer algo aqui caso o texto do edit não for 'B'

def arranque():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(950, 700)
    root.wm_iconbitmap('virtual-pc-1338544131.ico')
    root.title("Computador virtual PowerBIT v1.0")
    root.configure(background='black')

    machine = Label(root, text="Bem vindo à máquina virtual. Prima B para aceder ao BIOS ou ENTER para inciar o SO", fg="white", bg="black").grid(row=0)
    e1 = Entry(root, bg="white", fg="black" )
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    botao_de_arranque = Button(root, text="Iniciar", command= lambda: btn_arranque(e1.get()), width=6).grid(row=3, column=1,) 
    root.mainloop()

arranque()
```